# Will we be able to « see » COVID (or any other viruses) in our environment in the future?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, computer-vision

Given that cameras, computer vision and AI are constantly evolving with greater zoom, macro, processing power... is it possible that some day cameras would be able to « scan » a room and detect COVID (or any other viruses) somewhere, such as on the door knob? In other words, could evolved cameras and AI be able to see and track viruses in our environment?

Comment: This is possible today. The light needs to be UV, since the virion is about 100nm and visible light goes from 310 nm to 1100 nm. You have to get many microscopic images of a large area. So, you get huge amounts of data to process. It is just the wrong approach to the problem since it solves a much stronger problem "Seeing one virion" as opposed to detecting existence and in a macroscopic area. It is more effective to just swipe the door knob, then concentrate the virus further with other techniques and then do the observation.

Comment: I'm not sure that this interesting question is within the scope of this site.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus What site would you recommend?

Comment: I’m not aware of any such site on the network.